# Why is tf.gradients() function returning TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the tf.gradients() function to return the gradients between a set of values and a model, but it keeps giving me errors.

The error it return from the `sess.run()` line is `TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>` but I haven't specified any fetch arguments as far as I'm aware so I'm not really sure what's causing this.

Please could you help me understand where the error is coming from, thanks.

(Also I have noticed that when I print gradients it returns `[None, None]`, is that related?)

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class Model:
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, name="model"):

        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            self.feature_vector_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                                  shape=[None, input_dim],
                                                  name='feature_vector_')
            with tf.variable_scope('layer_1'):
                self.W_1 = tf.get_variable('W_1',
                                      shape=[input_dim, hidden_dim],
                                      initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
                hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(self.feature_vector_, self.W_1), name='hidden_1')

            with tf.variable_scope('layer_2'):
                self.W_2 = tf.get_variable('W_2', shape=[hidden_dim, 1],
                                      initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
                self.value = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(hidden_1, self.W_2), name='value')

            self.trainable_variables = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES,
                                                         scope=tf.get_variable_scope().name)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):

        model = Model(5,5,"test")

        model_value = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1))
        gradients = tf.gradients(model_value, model.trainable_variables)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        values = [1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]

        for i in range(0,len(values)):
            grads = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict={model_value:[values[i]]})
```

Here is the stack trace if it might be helful:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/tf-grads/toy_gradients_example", line 35, in <module>
    grads = sess.run(gradients, feed_dict={model_value:[values[i]]})
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\tf-grads\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\tf-grads\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1137, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\tf-grads\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 471, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\tf-grads\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 261, in for_fetch
    return _ListFetchMapper(fetch)
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\tf-grads\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 370, in __init__
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\tf-grads\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 370, in <listcomp>
    self._mappers = [_FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetch) for fetch in fetches]
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\tf-grads\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 258, in for_fetch
    type(fetch)))
TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Hi @shakety - Can you post the full traceback?

Comment: @RobTruxal I've added it to the question, thanks for taking a look :)

Comment: Looks like one of the elements within `gradients` is `None` & tensorflow isn't happy about it. 

If you put a `print(gradients)` above that `with tf.Session() as sess:` context line. What do you see?

Comment: @RobTruxal I get `[None, None]`, is that a problem? I thought it would work out the values when it was called?

Comment: Without knowing much about Tensorflow, that's what the traceback is telling me. The first argument of `tf.Session.run()` is called `fetches` (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run)  If you follow the `gradients` var back in your code, it comes from the `tf.gradients()` function which is supposed to return "a list of `sum(dy/dx)` for each x in `dx`" (see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients#returns) this is probably not supposed to be `None`, so that's where I'd start if I were you.